Conceptual definition of the Auslander-Reiten translate
In homological algebra, we learn to differentiate between

The conceptual definition.
A computation, which is done by choosing efficient resolutions.

The only definition I've seen of the Auslander-Reiten translate is via 2; one chooses resolutions by projective covers $P_1 \to P_0 \to M$ to define $Tr(M)$ and then take $\tau(M) = DTr(M)$.
What is the conceptual "coordinate free" definition of the Auslander-Reiten translate?

I’m not quite sure what you’re looking for, as I don’t see what is coordinate unfree about the definition you give. But do you know of the concept of almost split sequences (a.k.a. Auslander-Reiten sequences)?

I assume by "coordinate free" the OP means not involving a choice of resolution.

@JeremyRickard I have, and they do give a definition. However it takes a lot of theory that factors through homological algebra to obtain that definition. I hoped there is a cleaner approach.
